# bind json data from url to div using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am hitting one url and getting json data , this data i want to bind to different div.
json data sample from url is

```
[{"CompanyCode":"17023928","LastTradedPrice":"19,849.65","Symbol":"NSE"},{"CompanyCode":"17023929","LastTradedPrice":"6,021.25","Symbol":"NIFTY"}]
```

in this i have data for different symbol and i have two different div same name as symbol.I want to bind that data to div.
div format is

```
<div id="nse" >
 <div id="companyCode"></div>
 <div id="TradePrice"></div>
</div>
<div id="nifty" >
  <div id="companyCode"></div>
  <div id="TradePrice"></div>
</div>
```

for nse i want nse json to bind and for nifty , nifty data to bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next construction

```
<!-- ko foreach: myData -->
<!-- ko if : $data.Symbol === "NSE" -->
<div id="nse" >
 <span>This is NSE</span>
 <div id="companyCode" data-bind="text : $data.CompanyCode"></div>
 <div id="TradePrice"  data-bind="text : $data.LastTradedPrice"></div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if : $data.Symbol === "NIFTY" -->
<div id="nifty" >
 <span>This is NIFTY</span>
 <div id="companyCode" data-bind="text : $data.CompanyCode"></div>
 <div id="TradePrice"  data-bind="text : $data.LastTradedPrice"></div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VpUnz/)

or you can use [**knockout-swith-case**](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) plugin

**EDIT:**

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) { 
   self.myData =ko.observableArray(data); 
})
```

you should define `myData` as part of `viewModel` out of ajax request e.g

```
self.myData =ko.observableArray(data);   
$.getJSON(url, function (data) { 
    self.myData(data); 
})
```

Comment: This is gr8 answer....worked for me but i have one query if i am passing static json obj it worked for me. live var DATA=[{"CompanyCode":"17023928","LastTradedPrice":"19,849.65","Symbol":"NSE"},{"CompanyCode":"17023929","LastTradedPrice":"6,021.25","Symbol":"NIFTY"}] .  And if i want to load it from url it is saying Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings,Message: ReferenceError: myData is not defined. My code for getting data from url is like this in view model i wrote $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
           self.myData =ko.observableArray(data);
            });

Comment: I tried this before it was saying data is not defined...then i defined the var data='' like this. Now it is saying Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in  at file:///android_asset/www/js/knockout-2.2.0rc.debug.js:1046...... what should i do...

Comment: @vishalg also use `$data.myData` instead of `myData`

Comment: can u just tell me where it is exactly....because after putting this also giving the same error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in  at file:///android_asset/www/js/knockout-2.2.0rc.debug.js:1046

Comment: Thanks @llya for helping me out...it works for me by just adding  self.myData = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(data));

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var A = [{ "CompanyCode": "111", "LastTradedPrice": "11,1", "Symbol": "NSE" }, { "CompanyCode": "567", "LastTradedPrice": "8568", "Symbol": "NIFTY" }, { "CompanyCode": "gjgh78", "LastTradedPrice": "56856", "Symbol": "NSE" }, { "CompanyCode": "ghj65g", "LastTradedPrice": "56675", "Symbol": "NIFTY"}];
            $('#tblNSE,tblNIFTY').empty();
            $.each(A, function(key, value) {
                if (value.Symbol == 'NSE') {
                    $('#tblNSE').append('<tr><td>Company Code : </td><td>' + value.CompanyCode + '</td><td>Last Traded Price : </td><td>' + value.LastTradedPrice + '</tr>');
                } else {
                    $('#tblNIFTY').append('<tr><td>Company Code : </td><td>' + value.CompanyCode + '</td><td>Last Traded Price : </td><td>' + value.LastTradedPrice + '</tr>');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nse">
        <label>
            NSE
        </label>
        <table id="tblNSE">
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="nifty">
        <label>
            NIFTY
        </label>
        <table id="tblNIFTY">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```